# Initiation of vmVariables that are not persistent?

Tags: mdriven

If I declare a variable of a class that is not persistent in a VM; Do I need to initiate it and how? Pure declaration does not seem to do the trick. A create statement in the onShow statement in the navigation action to the page does not seem to do the trick either? Bug or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you have a variable that is typed as a class - and you need to init the variable by instansiating an object? Do this in onshow like in the image below:

[image: Mdriven init of variable that has a class type]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there's several confusing things in your question.

Are we talking about a transient class with attributes?

Variables in a viewmodel?  Variables in a viewmodel are always transient (non-persistent).